# How to delete the Anaconda Environment that VisualStudio is running in?

Tags: python

I've tried conda deactivate and then set the auto activate to false in the VS terminal but then when I run code the base activates again and I'm back in the virtual environment. I'm on Mac OS

Comment: Have you a `venv` folder under your project folder ?

Comment: Yes I do i looked and theres a venv folder @ChihebNexus

Comment: well rename your venv to other name and VS will not activate it by default

Comment: I just renamed the venv folder and checked again but I'm still in the base virtual environment @ChihebNexus